# Creating single WearOS package with app+widget from Qt5

Tags: android, qt5, wear-os

I'm considering building a WearOS app (for Samsung Galaxy Watch 6).  There will be the core app, as well as a widget (accessible by spinning the bezel on the watch)

This was easy on the Tizen development environment because of the templates.  But since I want to develop in Qt5/C++ I'm outside the 'supported' ecosystem.

Has anyone done this?